# Insert Function of Dual-Parameter Binary Tree (C++)

Tags: c++, nodes, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement an insert function for a binary search tree. While my logic does seem like it should work, when I try and run it through a tester function that turns it into a paired list I keep getting a list size which is 1 too big. This only seems to occur when I try to insert more than one repeated key, ie 2 instances of "cat" and 2 instances of "fish," otherwise it works flawlessly.

```
void insert (K k, V v)
{


  TreeNode<K,V> * treeNode = new TreeNode<K,V> (k,v);
  TreeNode<K,V> *temp=NULL;
  TreeNode<K,V> *prev=NULL;
  temp = root;

  while(temp) { 
    prev = temp;
    if(temp->key == treeNode->key)
    {
        temp->value = treeNode->value;
        sizeCount--;
        cout<<"REPLACEMENT MADE"<<endl;  //This outputs as many times as it should
        return; //This is what I was missing

    }
    if (temp->key < treeNode->key)
      {
        temp = temp->right;
      }
    else
      {
      temp = temp->left;
      }

  }

  if (prev==NULL)
    {root = treeNode;heightCount++;}
  else {
    if (prev->key<treeNode->key)
      {
        prev->right = treeNode;  

      }
    if(prev->key>treeNode->key)
      {
        prev->left = treeNode;

      }


  } 

    sizeCount++;

}
```

I'll note that I seem to have trouble striking a good balance between compact code and providing enough information. I can provide more code if requested.

Comment: Why do you change `sizeCount` when you replace value?

Comment: I've updated the code, it's because sizeCount always increments up at the end of the function. Deleted a line by mistake when compacting the code.

Comment: I'll also note that sizeCount, while not used in the problem area, actually does always display the proper value. So I'm getting proper REPLACEMENT and size outputs, but not when it's converted into a list...

Comment: So maybe error occurs when you're making list?

Comment: Highly doubtful, the list is provided as a preconfigured tester function, I can safely assume it's implemented correctly.

Comment: It is strange, that when you replaced value, you don't exit from the function That is where error happens.

Comment: Dude, you have absolutely no concept of how amazing this was. It's now almost 4am, and I've been working since midnight trying to get this code to work. That one line change did it. Please add this as an answer, I'd like to choose it. Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you insert key which is already present in a tree you replace the value of that node. But you don't exit the function with return, so `while` continues execution. As `temp->key` is equal to `treeNode->key` so you enter the `else` and `temp = temp->left;` happens. Then, when execution goes out of while your code may actually make incorrect structure.

Solution is to add `return;` to the place where replacement is actually made.